# Why don't simulated mouse clicks trigger focus event / text cursor?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, html-input, onfocus

I am attempting to redirect a click event from some element that is on screen to a text input that is off screen. Clicking on the element that is on screen triggers a handler that simulates the same event on the off-screen element.

When a user clicks a text input via the browser, both the focus and click handlers for the text input fire. However, when the simulated click event is dispatched on the off-screen text input no focus event occurs.

Further, when a simulated focus event is fired on a text input, the cursor does not appear in the text input as if the text input had been clicked.

Runnable snippet available at http://jsfiddle.net/k32n30vf/2/ since SO doesn't support CoffeeScript.

**Code (CoffeeScript)**

```
one = document.getElementById("one")
two = document.getElementById("two")
logger = document.getElementById("log")

#In order for the span to be focusable, it must have tabIndex != -1
one.tabIndex = 0

#Adds text to top of logger paragraph
log = (message) -> 
  entry = document.createElement('p')
  entry.classList.add("log")
  entry.innerText = message
  logger.insertBefore(entry, logger.firstChild)

#Event listener that logs events w / source
reportEvent = (event) -> log("#{event.currentTarget.id} #{event.type}")

#Listen on click and focus for both elements
e.addEventListener "click", reportEvent, false for e in [one, two]
e.addEventListener "focus", reportEvent, false for e in [one, two]

#Generic simulate method
simulate = (what, where) -> 
  where = if where == "one" then one else two
  what = if what == "click" then new MouseEvent("click") else new FocusEvent("focus")
  where.dispatchEvent what

#Wire up buttons
document.getElementById("sim-one-clk").addEventListener("click", () -> simulate("click", "one"))
document.getElementById("sim-two-clk").addEventListener("click", () -> simulate("click", "two"))
document.getElementById("sim-one-fcs").addEventListener("focus", () -> simulate("focus", "one"))
document.getElementById("sim-two-fcs").addEventListener("focus", () -> simulate("focus", "two"))
```

**CSS**

```
p.log {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p> Instructions:</p>
    <ol>
        <li> Click "Simulate Click on #2"</li>
        <li> Note how no text cursor appears on input</li>
        <li> Actually click on input</li>
        <li> Note how text cursor appears on input</li>
    </ol>
<p><span id="one">This span is #1</span>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="two" value="this input is #2"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="sim-one-clk" type="button" value="Simulate Click on #1"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="sim-one-fcs" type="button" value="Simulate Focus on #1"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="sim-two-clk" type="button" value="Simulate Click on #2"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="sim-two-fcs" type="button" value="Simulate Focus on #2"></input>
</p>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Notice that if the on screen element is focused and the <kbd>Simulate Click on #2</kbd> button is pressed, the text cursor does not appear in the off screen element. However clicking on the off screen element results in the text cursor appearing.

Comment: hard to make much sense of this demo. Click on `on screen focus` it logs `offscreen`. No idea what the `off screen` even means when all is visible

Comment: @charlietfl The on/off mismatch was a minor bug in demo, which is now fixed. The "off screen" element is of course displayed on the screen for the purpose of the demo so you can see the effect. In the actual code it is off screen.

Comment: @charlietfl updated text to say "one" and "two" instead of "on screen" and "off screen". Added instructions.